# Set DataTemplate in template selector as dynamic resource

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a control in which I need to set data template based on various conditions so I decided to use a `DataTemplateSelector` which selects templates from resources of the control its being assigned to.

This works, but here is a catch: I am reloading these resources from file (when there is file system change) and I need to update already rendered controls with the new template. This would work if I simply used `DynamicResource` instead of selector.

Selector looks something like this:

```
public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container) {
  //complex rules that select the template are here
  //this unfortunately sets the template statically - if it changes, it won't get updated
  return template;
}
```

So if the resources change, the selector is never reevaluated as it would be if I used `DynamicResource`.

I had an idea to solve this: select the template in ViewModel, so that when resources change, I can update my `DataTemplate` property.

My attempt of ViewModel (simplified example, it implements INotifyPropertyChange properly):

```
class MyViewModel {
  public DataTemplate DataTemplate {get;set;}

  public MyModel Model {
    get {return _model;}
    set {
      if(_model != value) {
        _model = value;
        //Select new template here
        //DUH: how do I access the resources as I would in DataTemplateSelector, when I don't have access to the container parameter?
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am pretty sure that I am doing this the wrong way, but how to do it properly? I don't want to access the resources from some hard-coded static location for various reasons. I really need to find them in the container it is being assigned to.

I know the question is confusing, so feel free to ask and I will try to clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after long hours of trying to figure this out using various hackish methods, it showed to be really easily solvable problem.

We set our data template (only key to data template in fact) in view-model and then apply the template in simple attached property.

xaml:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding Content}" local:ContentTemplate.ContentTemplateKey="{Binding TemplateKey}">
    <!-- Some other stuff -->
</ContentControl>
```

attached property:

```
public static class ContentTemplate
{

    public static object GetContentTemplateKey(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (object)obj.GetValue(ContentTemplateKeyProperty);
    }

    public static void SetContentTemplateKey(DependencyObject obj, object value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(ContentTemplateKeyProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ContentTemplateKeyProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ContentTemplateKey", typeof(object), typeof(ContentTemplate), new UIPropertyMetadata(null, OnContentTemplateKeyChanged));

    private static void OnContentTemplateKeyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var key = e.NewValue;

        var element = d as FrameworkElement;
        if (element == null)
            return;

        element.SetResourceReference(ContentControl.ContentTemplateProperty, key);
    }
}
```

binding object if resource uses `x:Key="ResourceName"`:

```
new
{
    Content = something,
    TemplateKey = "ResourceName",
}
```

binding object if resource uses `TargetType="{x:Type Person}"`:

```
new
{
    Content = something,
    TemplateKey = new DataTemplateKey(typeof(Person)),
}
```

Of course the binding object should implement INotifyPropertyChange so the templates update on the fly.